# rxjs BehaviorSubject next() called in a forEach loop causing network req to be cancelled

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a really fun rxjs problem to solve...

1. So I have a function that receives an array of objects from my csv parser component `uploadCSV()`
2. this then splits the array into new arrays => items to be updates `line: 10` => items to be created `line: 11`
3. I then do a foreach loop and send each object to the BehaviorSubject and increment the counters respectively.

The problem I am having is that this basically fires the first object off, but then I can see in the networks tool that all the subsequent requests are being canceled. I am assuming this is because the observable is receiving a new value before the request is completed.

Not sure how to solve this? dinstinctUntilChanged and debounce maybe?

```
uploadCSV() {
    const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
    dialogConfig.autoFocus = true;
    dialogConfig.width = '100vw';

    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DataUploadComponent, dialogConfig);

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(airlines => {
        airlines = airlines.map(airline => ({...airline, id: +airline.id}));
        const update = airlines.filter(airline => this.airlines.some(item => item.id === airline.id));
        const create = airlines.filter(airline => !this.airlines.some(item => item.id === airline.id));
        create.forEach(item => {
            this.newAirlineSubject$.next(item);
            this.created = ++this.created;
        });
        update.forEach(item => {
            this.updateAirlineSubject$.next(item);
            this.updated = ++this.updated;
        });
        this.snackBar.open(
            `${this.updated} items updated : ${this.created} items created`, null,
            {
                duration: 3000
            });
        this.snackBar._openedSnackBarRef.afterOpened().subscribe(() => this.updated = this.created = 0);
    });
}

const newAirline$ = this.newAirlineSubject$
    .pipe(
        filter(airline => !!airline),
        tap(() => this.saveStatus = 1),
        switchMap(airline => this.airlineService.newAirline(airline)),
        tap(() => this.saveStatus = 2),
        map(airline => {
            this.airlines = [airline, ...this.airlines];
            return this.airlines;
        }),
        tap(() => this.saveStatus = 0),
        shareReplay()
    );

const updateAirline$ = this.updateAirlineSubject$
    .pipe(
        filter(airline => !!airline),
        tap(() => this.saveStatus = 1),
        switchMap(airline => this.airlineService.updateAirline(airline)),
        tap(() => this.saveStatus = 2),
        map(airline => {
            const index = this.airlines.findIndex(item => item.id === airline.id);
            this.airlines = [...this.airlines, this.airlines[index] = airline];
            return this.airlines;
        }),
        tap(() => this.saveStatus = 0),
        shareReplay()
    );

const airlines$ = this.airlineService.getAllAirlines()
    .pipe(
        map(airlines => {
            this.airlines = [...airlines];
            return this.airlines;
        }),
        shareReplay()
    );

this.airlines$ = airlines$.pipe(
    merge(newAirline$, updateAirline$)
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `switchMap` to `concatMap` because you `next()` in a for loop, it'll emit synchronously and switchMap will unsubscribe the inner observable once the source emit, so you will end up having the last emitted value only.

```
const newAirline$ = this.newAirlineSubject$
    .pipe(
        filter(airline => !!airline),
        tap(() => this.saveStatus = 1),
        concatMap(airline => this.airlineService.newAirline(airline)),
        tap(() => this.saveStatus = 2),
        map(airline => {
            this.airlines = [airline, ...this.airlines];
            return this.airlines;
        }),
        tap(() => this.saveStatus = 0),
        shareReplay()
    );

const updateAirline$ = this.updateAirlineSubject$
    .pipe(
        filter(airline => !!airline),
        tap(() => this.saveStatus = 1),
        concatMap(airline => this.airlineService.updateAirline(airline)),
        tap(() => this.saveStatus = 2),
        map(airline => {
            const index = this.airlines.findIndex(item => item.id === airline.id);
            this.airlines = [...this.airlines, this.airlines[index] = airline];
            return this.airlines;
        }),
        tap(() => this.saveStatus = 0),
        shareReplay()
    );
```

Comment: It is worth noticing that if OP cares about the order in which the requests are sent to the backend, then your answer is correct. Otherwise, he could optionally use `mergeMap` instead of `concatMap`

Comment: Agree with ur comment

Comment: Also worth mentioning that shareReplay() is the key factor that helps with the issue.

Answer (score -2):

It's hard to get the complete picture without seeing `airlineService.newAirline`. I'm suspicious of `this.saveStatus` again I'd have to see more code to understand what its purpose is, but as each new item is emitted, this will get set back to 1 for *all* items. I assume this is not what you want happening. If you could clarify on those two it'd help.

As an aside, this is some weird stuff right here:

```
    const update = airlines.filter(airline => this.airlines.some(item => item.id === airline.id));
    const create = airlines.filter(airline => !this.airlines.some(item => item.id === airline.id));
```

Edit: Apologies, I missed the `this` and interpreted `airlines` and `this.airlines` to be the same array - that would have been weird...